# Ubercart Discounts (alternative) applies discount to all items in cart (drupal 6)

Tags: 6, ubercart

I've created some bulk discounts to be applied when the number of products added to the cart is between specific ranges (e.g. Minimum qualification amount = 10 & Maximum qualification amount = 29).
The problem is that whenever a product qualifies for discount, that discount is applied to all the products in the cart. That's because a condition of qualification requires the product to have a "Bulk Discount" term applied to it. Also, the discount is set to be applied to products tagged with the "Bulk Discount" term.
The solution to this would be to have a different taxonomy term for every product and set a different discount for each one of them. But this would definitely not be practical.

```
Example:

product1: price = $10, product2: price = $30
Cart contains: 10 x product1, 3 x product2
Discount triggered by qualification rule for product1: -10%
Order total = (10x10 + 3x30)x0.9 = $171
What I want the order total to be = (10x10)x0.9 + 3x30 = $180
```

Is there any way to do that using that module?

Comment: You are using module that is seeking co-maintainers, last release was 2011-Sep-27 (about 3 years ago) and have 99 open issues in issue queue. Are you sure it was a smart move? Also, documentation is unclear (for me) if what you see is a bug, or an expected behaviour.

Comment: My question was not if I should use this module or not.
I didn't just start using the module, it was implemented on the website a couple of years ago. What I describe is probably expected behavior but I'm not 100% sure and wondered if there are other ways to configure the discounts.

Comment: *"My question was not if..."* - yes, I know, that's why I haven't posted this as an answer, merely a comment. Anyway, given that all documentation seems to be readme, module page and module itself, and maintainer is no longer active, I doubt you will get your answer.